# too many values to unpack (expected 2) when going from 2D list to dict? (Python)

Tags: python, list, dictionary, dictionary-comprehension

I have a list of 2 item lists, as shown below:

```
list_of_parsed_rows =
[['ADP:', 'Round: 1, Pick: 2'],
 ['Team:', 'Carolina Panthers'],
 ['Ht / Wt:', '5\'11" / 202 lb.'],
 ['College:', 'Stanford'],
 ['Age:', '24'],
 ['Born:', 'June 7, 1996'],
 ['Drafted:', '2017 /\n\nRd. 1 (8)'],
 ['Draft Team:', 'CAR'],
 ['Saquon Barkley', 'RB', 'NYG', '1.02'],
 ['Ezekiel Elliott', 'RB', 'DAL', '1.04'],
 ['Derrick Henry', 'RB', 'TEN', '1.04'],
 ['Dalvin Cook', 'RB', 'MIN', '1.05'],
 ['Alvin Kamara', 'RB', 'NO', '1.06'],
 ['Michael Thomas', 'WR', 'NO', '1.08'],
 ['Josh Jacobs', 'RB', 'LV', '1.08'],
 ['Nick Chubb', 'RB', 'CLE', '1.09'],
 ['Aaron Jones', 'RB', 'GB', '1.10'],
 ['Tyreek Hill', 'WR', 'KC', '1.11'],
 ['Joe Mixon', 'RB', 'CIN', '1.11'],
 ['Pat Mahomes', 'QB', 'KC', '2.01'],
 ['Davante Adams', 'WR', 'GB', '2.01'],
 ['DeAndre Hopkins', 'WR', 'ARI', '2.02'],
 ['Miles Sanders', 'RB', 'PHI', '2.03']]
```

And I'm trying to turn it into a dict with the following

```
dict_of_parsed_rows = {key: value for key, value in list_of_parsed_rows}
```

But I get the following error message:

```
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Any idea what's happening? What's strange is this is the exact solution to a problem in a book, and I'm surprised it would be incorrect.

Comment: What do you expect to get as the `value` for the row `['Joe Mixon', 'RB', 'CIN', '1.11']`, for example?

Comment: there are n items in each row.  hence trying to pick a tuple of two values fails.  potentially you are trying to achieve `{row[0]:row[1:] for row in list_of_parsed_rows}` which says 1st element of list is the key and the rest of the list is the value

Answer (score 0):

You are looping over a nested list and the inner list has varying length.
Hence, python can't unpack many values.

Assuming you want the first element to be key and remaining elements to be value, you need to join the remaining elements to form a string

```
In [2]: list_of_parsed_rows =[['ADP:', 'Round: 1, Pick: 2'],
   ...:  ['Team:', 'Carolina Panthers'],
   ...:  ['Ht / Wt:', '5\'11" / 202 lb.'],
   ...:  ['College:', 'Stanford'],
   ...:  ['Age:', '24'],
   ...:  ['Born:', 'June 7, 1996'],
   ...:  ['Drafted:', '2017 /\n\nRd. 1 (8)'],
   ...:  ['Draft Team:', 'CAR'],
   ...:  ['Saquon Barkley', 'RB', 'NYG', '1.02'],
   ...:  ['Ezekiel Elliott', 'RB', 'DAL', '1.04'],
   ...:  ['Derrick Henry', 'RB', 'TEN', '1.04'],
   ...:  ['Dalvin Cook', 'RB', 'MIN', '1.05'],
   ...:  ['Alvin Kamara', 'RB', 'NO', '1.06'],
   ...:  ['Michael Thomas', 'WR', 'NO', '1.08'],
   ...:  ['Josh Jacobs', 'RB', 'LV', '1.08'],
   ...:  ['Nick Chubb', 'RB', 'CLE', '1.09'],
   ...:  ['Aaron Jones', 'RB', 'GB', '1.10'],
   ...:  ['Tyreek Hill', 'WR', 'KC', '1.11'],
   ...:  ['Joe Mixon', 'RB', 'CIN', '1.11'],
   ...:  ['Pat Mahomes', 'QB', 'KC', '2.01'],
   ...:  ['Davante Adams', 'WR', 'GB', '2.01'],
   ...:  ['DeAndre Hopkins', 'WR', 'ARI', '2.02'],
   ...:  ['Miles Sanders', 'RB', 'PHI', '2.03']]

In [3]: dict_of_parsed_rows = {innerlist[0]:",".join(innerlist[1:]) for innerlist in list_of_parsed_rows}

In [4]: dict_of_parsed_rows
Out[4]:
{'ADP:': 'Round: 1, Pick: 2',
 'Team:': 'Carolina Panthers',
 'Ht / Wt:': '5\'11" / 202 lb.',
 'College:': 'Stanford',
 'Age:': '24',
 'Born:': 'June 7, 1996',
 'Drafted:': '2017 /\n\nRd. 1 (8)',
 'Draft Team:': 'CAR',
 'Saquon Barkley': 'RB,NYG,1.02',
 'Ezekiel Elliott': 'RB,DAL,1.04',
 'Derrick Henry': 'RB,TEN,1.04',
 'Dalvin Cook': 'RB,MIN,1.05',
 'Alvin Kamara': 'RB,NO,1.06',
 'Michael Thomas': 'WR,NO,1.08',
 'Josh Jacobs': 'RB,LV,1.08',
 'Nick Chubb': 'RB,CLE,1.09',
 'Aaron Jones': 'RB,GB,1.10',
 'Tyreek Hill': 'WR,KC,1.11',
 'Joe Mixon': 'RB,CIN,1.11',
 'Pat Mahomes': 'QB,KC,2.01',
 'Davante Adams': 'WR,GB,2.01',
 'DeAndre Hopkins': 'WR,ARI,2.02',
 'Miles Sanders': 'RB,PHI,2.03'}
```

If you want the second element to be the value

```
dict_of_parsed_rows = {key: value for key,value, *k in list_of_parsed_rows}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use list comprehension for dict like this. Python does not understand you meant `list[0]` as key, and `list[1]` as value. But you can do it with a singe loop.

```
list_of_parsed_rows = [['ADP:', 'Round: 1, Pick: 2'],
 ['Team:', 'Carolina Panthers'],
 ['Ht / Wt:', '5\'11" / 202 lb.'],
 ['College:', 'Stanford'],
 ['Age:', '24'],
 ['Born:', 'June 7, 1996'],
 ['Drafted:', '2017 /\n\nRd. 1 (8)'],
 ['Draft Team:', 'CAR'],
 ['Saquon Barkley', 'RB', 'NYG', '1.02'],
 ['Ezekiel Elliott', 'RB', 'DAL', '1.04'],
 ['Derrick Henry', 'RB', 'TEN', '1.04'],
 ['Dalvin Cook', 'RB', 'MIN', '1.05'],
 ['Alvin Kamara', 'RB', 'NO', '1.06'],
 ['Michael Thomas', 'WR', 'NO', '1.08'],
 ['Josh Jacobs', 'RB', 'LV', '1.08'],
 ['Nick Chubb', 'RB', 'CLE', '1.09'],
 ['Aaron Jones', 'RB', 'GB', '1.10'],
 ['Tyreek Hill', 'WR', 'KC', '1.11'],
 ['Joe Mixon', 'RB', 'CIN', '1.11'],
 ['Pat Mahomes', 'QB', 'KC', '2.01'],
 ['Davante Adams', 'WR', 'GB', '2.01'],
 ['DeAndre Hopkins', 'WR', 'ARI', '2.02'],
 ['Miles Sanders', 'RB', 'PHI', '2.03']]

dict_of_parsed_rows = dict()

for elem in list_of_parsed_rows:
    dict_of_parsed_rows[elem[0]] = elem[1:]

print(dict_of_parsed_rows)
```

Comment: This will discard the rest of the values, resulting in a data loss.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a filter in a list comprehension to omit the lists that have other than 2 items:

```
dict_of_parsed_rows = dict([l for l in list_of_parsed_rows if len(l) == 2])
```

Answer (score 0):

In the example it is not defined what would be the `value` when there are more than 2 items, such as:

```
['Saquon Barkley', 'RB', 'NYG', '1.02'],
```

If you want to keep the first element (e.g. `'Saquon Barkley'`) as the key and combine the rest of the values in a `list` (e.g. `['RB', 'NYG', '1.02']`) and use as your `value`, a simple fix would be to use the unpack operator (`*`):

```
dict_of_parsed_rows = {key: value for key, *value in list_of_parsed_rows}
```